# Why it is not good to use "!= null" to test if argument is passed

Tags: javascript

From the book Maintainable JavaScript it mentioned :

```
// Bad: Testing to see if an argument was passed
function doSomething(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4){
if (arg4 != null){
    doSomethingElse();
  }
}
```

but I feel using `!= null` here is quite effective, it filtered both the case of argument not passed or it is passed as null

any reason why the author suggest it is bad ?

Comment: How should we know what the author was thinking? Ask the author!

Comment: I assume this advice is offered because it is useful to distinguish between `null` and no argument. `undefined` usually means "not yet given a value" while `null` usually means "deliberately given a value of nothing".

Comment: The explanation is on the page before the one that has the code you posted.

Comment: It's not at all bad, and is probably one of the most appropriate uses of `==`. But ultimately it depends on what you're trying to guard against.

Answer (score 9):

`!= null` is false for `undefined`, it basically means `x !== null && x !== undefined`. `!=` does type coercion, and one of the effects of that is that it treats `null` and `undefined` as equivalent (`null == undefined` is true).

So unless you want that, some people recommend not using `!=` with `null` (or `undefined`).

And you're quite right that the code defends against two (well actually three) possibilities:

1. Nothing was passed for the argument *at all*.
2. `null` was passed.
3. `undefined` was passed.

But the comment says it's a bad way to test whether an argument was passed, and it is: Because it doesn't catch passing `null` or `undefined`. (Passing in `null` and not passing in *anything* are different cases.) That doesn't necessarily mean it's a bad way to check the argument for a specific function.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. In javascript you can have `null` values and `undefined` values. And they're not the same. A fast and easy approach to check if the arg is valid would probably be:

`if (arg4)`

And this way you check arg4 is not null, not undefined, and **not false**. Please be careful with this last condition, you may inform a false value consciously here :-)

*EDIT: T.J. Crowder is right here. It's easy to use this and will work in most cases, but be careful.*

Comment: Best answer, unless arg4 is a Boolean :)

Comment: *"The best approach to check if the arg is valid would probably be"* No, that will also weed out `""`, `0`, `NaN`, and `false` (in addition to `null` and `undefined`). There are lots of times when that will bite you. It's a great check for optional *object* arguments, but other than those, it gets dicey. (Not my dv)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend watching http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare - a brilliant presentation on this matter from the man who created it himself.

Answer (score -1):

Because you can pass anything to a function, also *null*. If you would to the following:

```js
var obj = new MyObject();
// ...
obj = null;
// ...
doSomething(arg1, arg2, arg3, obj);
```

You would have passed an argument but your checking would fail because the passed reference is *null*. Always use the following:

```js
if(typeof arg4 != 'undefined')
    // ...
```

Comment: Why would the checking fail? Seems clear that the code intends to also guard against `null`.

Comment: To be fair, `obj = undefined` *should* be identical to omitting an argument. You should address the difference between `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: @CrazyTrain The author of the original code example was trying to explain that *unless you want to guard against `null`*, don't check against `!= null`. Checking against `null` is offered (in this case) as a *defect* of the code, where the actual intent is only to test the number of defined arguments.

Comment: @apsillers: So the author is saying don't exclude values that you want to include. Good advice.